# Access key of object using *ngFor

Tags: angular

I would like to get the key :337 using *ngfor.
any idea please !! [this the output of array of objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfOuD.png)

Comment: what do you mean by the key?

Comment: *ngFor="let item of items; let i =index" than you can use i

Comment: I have a multidimensional array and each array contains objects and have a key like a picture. I like to get the number 337 for example

Comment: *ngFor="let item of items; let last =last;let i =index" <div *ngIf="last">{{ index }}</div>